Looking for a 1980s or 1990s movie set on a spaceship. Hero is aided by a friend recovered from suspended animation
The movie is set on a spaceship. I can't recall any actors. I thought the star might be Michael Pare, but the closest movie I could find with him is "The Deadly Wake" (2013), which is not it. Then I thought perhaps Olivier Gruner in "Velocity Trap," but that was also wrong. The only thing I can recall about it is there is some sort of takeover of the ship in progress. The hero tries to stop it and is aided by a short silvery spiky-haired man who is brought out of suspended animation with a pool cue.

No the fellow coming out of suspended animation has one in the tank with him. I guess he liked playing pool. Also thought the hero was a well known actor but can't recall who.

No I believe it was an actual pool cue for billiards.

frozen I believe but O don't think it's the Lockout movie as that is a 2012 flick. I'm guessing the one I am thinking of is mid 80's to mid 90's.

I believe the tank was horizontal so the dude would have lying on his back.

No not the Caper Van Dien movie.

Lockout has a space-based prison takeover and an ally coming out of suspended animation. I do not remember a pool cue but there are some melee  weapons used. 
